# Node js chatting with multiple users in same room

Tags: node.js, sockets

I am new to node.js. I am creating a chat app. I want to manage 4 users who are connected to the room. I have the primary key of the logged in user `User A` in the session, I can also save it in hidden file. When the page loads I only have one socket connected to server (i.e. socket of `User A`). When `user A` wants to chat with `User B`, I have a textarea for message, a div to show the chat message history and one send button.

How can I allow `user A` to chat with N number of users and keep track of who's chatting who?

I am thinking of following method to keep track of the chat messages,

> Save both users primary key in hidden fields. When user A send message
>   to User B. Send User A and B's PK to server along with message and
>   save it in database.

or...

> Is there any way to identify User B's Socket. So that Saving/Handling
>   User A and B's primary on client side can be avoided.

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

You can broadcast the message to all connected users.

```
io.sockets.emit("method","Message");
```

or you can send message to the specific user socket

```
 io.sockets.socket(socketId).emit("method","Message");
```

Also you can add the users to the specific room on connection

```
  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.join("RoomName");
  });
```

and send message to the room ( Message will deliver to all joined users )

```
io.to('RoomName').emit("method","Message");
```

You can get the socket id of user on connection and save it to array or database .

```
  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log( "User connected on " + socket.id);
  });
```

Chat Application :

Node.js is single thread application.So You will have all connected user socket object stored in the io.sockets

```
 Step 1: Save socket id of user in to database on Connection 
 Step 2: Remove Socket id of user from database on connection
 Step 3: if socket id of user exist in database then this mean user is connected and you can send the message to user socket.
```

**Node.js**

```
// User Socket array storage 
var user_by_socket = [];
var socket_to_users = [];

   io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

   // Save Socket Object
   user_by_socket[socket.id] = socket; 
   socket_to_user["Jhon"] = socket;

   user_by_socket[socket.id] = socket; 
   socket_by_user["David"] = socket;


   //Send Message 
   socket.on('send',function(data){

   // Sent by username
   socket_by_user["David"].emit("recieve","{ "From" : 'Jhon' , 'message' :  "Hello" }");

   //Sent by Socket Id
   user_by_socket["Socket ID"].emit("recieve","{ "From" : 'Jhon' , 'message' :  "Hello" }");


   });


   });
```

Comment: Thanks Navneet for answer.... Correct me if am wrong, As far as i know we can only access socket of connected user. How can we access socket of users which are just fetched and listed from database with user Id and user name (in html <UL> and <LI>).

Comment: I have updated the answer,  In short, Yes you can access the socket of any connected user by fetching the socket id of user.   Remember, if socket is active then message will be sent, When user disconnect socket removed from the io.sockets

Comment: Ok Now I got that socket.id is supposed to uniquely identify a socket. So I have to save User info in an array during io.sockets.on connection.  For e.g.   USERARRAY[SOCKET.ID] = getUserIdFromDatabase(Session_Id_Of_Logged_In_User);     USERARRAY[SOCKET.ID][USERNAME] = {UserName_Of_Logged_In_User};  & so on.  And destroy socket info and session of USERARRAY[SOCKET.ID] on disconnect event....

Comment: I have added more code in to my answer, Check that. It's better to save users and sockets on both end

Comment: Thanks @navneetsingh, i am trying with  "user_by_socket".  i think it is more secure than "socket_to_users"